# Angular nested route outlet url pattern

Tags: angular, url, friendly-url

I have an Angular 8 application with this route definition:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginPageComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'admin', component: PrivateContentTemplateComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomePageComponent, outlet: 'private-content', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'products', component: ProductListPageComponent, outlet: 'private-content' }
    ]
  },
];
```

When I access the componente `ProductListPageComponent` the url pattern generated is: `http://localhost:4200/#/admin/(private-content:products)`.

This patten is so ugly!
How could I change to: `http://localhost:4200/#/admin/products`?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15338
Issue already open in Angular repo. Sadly, not fixed yet.